# Make array of object

Tags: arrays

I have data as below..
How to make an array of object.
For example `keywords[0]` and `probability[1]`.

Here is my json file:

```
{
  "response": {
    "description": "",
    "errorCode": "ERROR_SUCCESS",
    "internal": null
  },
  "result": {
    "keywords": {
      "en_us": {
        "galah": false,
        "masak": false,
        "merah": false,
        "search": true,
        "udang": false
      },
      "en_gb": {
        "galah": false,
        "masak": false,
        "merah": false,
        "search": true,
        "udang": false
      },
      "ms_my": {
        "galah": true,
        "masak": true,
        "merah": true,
        "search": false,
        "udang": true
      }
    },
    "probability": {
      "en_us": 0.2,
      "en_gb": 0.2,
      "ms_my": 0.8
    }
  },
  "time": 0.188148021698
}
```

I've tried this part and it works:

```
var dataKeyword = data.result.keywords;
var result = [];

        for(var i in dataKeyword)
            result.push([i,dataKeyword[i]]);

        $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it, if so, post the code you have worked with. it is easier to help you then do it for you

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like

```
'probability' : [{'en_us' : 0.2}, {'en_gb' : 0.2}, {'ms_my': 0.8}],
```

or like

[How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

Comment: 'probability' : [{'en_us' : 0.2}, {'en_gb' : 0.2}, {'ms_my': 0.8}],

Comment: Cool, can you mark it as 'answered' for me, with the tick. No worries